# Setting Values for a Parent Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a two models, venue and concerts. Concerts belong to a venue and venues have many concerts. In my form I am setting the concerts venue with a custom setter, the form looks like:

```
<%= form_for @concert do |f| %>      
      <%= f.label :venue_name, "Venue" %>
      <%= f.text_field :venue_name %>
```

Then in my model:

```
  def venue_name=(name)
    self.venue = Venue.find_or_create_by_name(name) if name.present?
  end
```

The problem with this is, I would also like to add an address to a model if it is being created. Is this possible with the child's form? Is it possible to pass both a name and an address to the setter?

Edit:

As the comment suggested below I've moved to using accepts_nested_attributes_for. Ryan Bates has a great screencast on this here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised or the documentation is fine too.

I was used accepts_nested for this before hand, but struggled as this is on the belongs_to side of things. My fix now that I've gone back is that, for this example, instead of doing @concert.venue.build, the syntax for the belongs_to side of things is @concert.build_venue

Comment: This sounds like a job for [nested attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you show your users that they can add the name and the address separated by a comma, at sign, semicolon, etc, on your model you can separate the two of them using a regex and insert each one of them separately.

```
def venue_name=(name)
  venue = name.split(',')[0] # The comma (,) can be any symbol
  address = name.split((',')[1]
  # Insert venue
  # Insert address
end
```

This is the ugly way.